# Accessing a Pointer to a pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

Hi I am using a 3rd party library in my iPhone application that uses C++ one of the methods i need to use returns a pointer to a pointer of a class. like follows.

```
DLL classAttributes** getAttributes();
```

I can successfully call the method and return the value into a pointer to a pointer like so;

```
classAttributes **attributes = cPPClass->getAttributes();
```

however i can't seem to access any of the methods on the class for example i know that the class has a function called getName(); but when i try calling it i get errors.

```
attributes->getName(); 'Request for member 'getName' in *attributes'; which is of non-class type 'attributes*''
```

I did some googling and found some stuff that said to access a pointer pointer address use the format

```
&(*attributes)->getName(); 'invalid uses of incomplete type 'struct attributes'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what the `->`, `*`, and `&` operators do?  If not, you need to find [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list) and learn what they are.  You can't stumble through programming C++ by trying random combinations of operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'invalid uses of incomplete type 'struct attributes'` indicates that you need to `#include` the header file for it. It's only forward-declared at this point in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about the library, it's hard to say.  But it could be returning an array of items:

```
attributes[0]->getName();    
attributes[1]->getName();
```

The questionable part about my guess, though, is that there is no obvious way to know how many items there are.

Comment: Note that `attributes[0]->getName()` is equivalent to `(*attributes)->getName()`.

Comment: @Kristopher:  Yes - I know that.  I'll try to clarify my meaning.  I added another entry to show more "array-like" usage (and a caveat that indicates I would not know how many items there are).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First consider what you would do if the function returned a pointer to a classAttributes variable. In this case, you would simply do:

```
attributes->getName();
```

Since it's a pointer to a pointer, you must first dereference it and then use the `->` operator:

```
(*attributes)->getName();
```

If this doesn't work, it may be a problem caused by the function not being implemented or by inheritance.

Comment: Hi Guys, I tried both those suggestions (*) and [0] but i still get the same error:: invalid use of incomplete type

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a classAttributes*.  Since you have a classAttribues** , you want to dereference it once to get to the classAttributes*.

```
(*attributes)
```

From there you can probably call the members of the class.

```
classAttributes **attributesArray = cPPClass->getAttributes();
classAttributes *attributesObject(*attributesArray);
attributesObject->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, you'd probably have to do is this way (i.e. no ampersand):

```
(*attributes)->getName();
```

This is because dereferencing it *once* will give you a pointer to a struct, on which you can then use the `->` operator. What's happening when you do `&(*attributes)` is that you're dereferencing the pointer, then getting the address of the object you have — in effect making it a no-op.